# How to see diff of each commit with Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've been trying to move over to Visual Studio Code from WebStorm but WebStorm still has this one killer feature that I can't see how to do in Visual Studio Code.

I can quickly pull up a list of my commits and then diff any one of them:

[image]

[image]

Please tell me Visual Studio Code has a way of doing this?

Comment: Are you referring to Visual Studio 2015/2017 or Visual Studio Code?

Comment: Its Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, it has built in `git` integration. Please refer to [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/introvideos/versioncontrol) tutorial. There are also plethora of [extensions](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=git&target=VSCode&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance), like `Git History` and `Git Project Manager`

[image: Git History extension result]

Comment: Its similar but I cant see a way of diffing by a commit rather than by a file.

Comment: After you install [`Git History`](https://github.com/DonJayamanne/gitHistoryVSCode) extension, you will get this ability. Command-Shit-P, select `Git: View History (git log)`. You will see all the commits, much like in your first picture. Then you can select the (commited) version you want to compare to.

Comment: You should summarize the content of those links in your answer to answer the question more specifically.

Answer (score 8):

1. Install the GitLens extension (or it's already installed by default)
2. Go to the GitLens tab in the sidebar
3. Find the row 'Search Commits'
4. Enter the commit SHA

You'll see all files that were changed in that commit.

[image: click to see photo!]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I don't think GitLens is installed by default but it is now integrated to the main source control tab.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Answer (score 3):

On Windows or Mac:

`Ctrl + Shift + G`

Then click on the "M" (short for Modified) next to the file that you wish to view diffing on.

Comment: Nothing happens after pressing `Ctrl + Shift + G`!

Comment: @Milan This still works for me on both Windows and Mac.

Comment: Oh, I have been trying in Linux (Ubuntu 18.04). So, I guess there would be a different command for Linux. Thanks for confirming for Windows & Mac though :)

Comment: @Milan Let me know so I can update the answer.

Comment: As of now, I don't know the equivalent command for `Ctrl + Shift + G` in Ubuntu. But as soon as I do, I would comment here. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For SVN you can use the extension called "SVN-EXT".

[image]